# how to create floating internal links container

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a page with internal jumper links to jump to the particular anchor tags or header tags within the same page..

i want the jumper links to be fixed on top as it is being scrolled by, and scroll with the footer as it reaches the footer..

and i want to scroll to the particular link without page refreshing as i click any of the quick links..

also i want to highlight the current anchor link being scrolled..

i tried to do this, but here is what i came up with..

```
function goToByScroll(hash) {
$(document.body).animate({
    'scrollTop':   $(hash).offset().top
}, 500);
   }

 var $links = $('#links');
 var $content = $('#content');
 height = $(window).height();

 $(window).scroll(function(){

if ($(window).scrollTop() >= height ){

    $links.css({ position:'fixed', top:'70px'});
    $content.css({ marginLeft: '80px'});

} else {

    $links.css({ position:'relative'});
    $content.css({ marginLeft: '9px'});

}

});
```

//http://jsfiddle.net/MfS3J/13/

basically i want to create something like this
[galaxy s4 review - the verge](http://www.theverge.com/2013/4/24/4257254/samsung-galaxy-s4-review)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Waypoint plugin http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

With this plugin you can trigger an event whenever the top (or the bottom) of the window reaches a certain element.

E.G.

```
$('#id_of_container').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if(direction=='down'){
    $(this).css('position','fixed');
  } else {
    $(this).css('position','');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it this you want? http://jsfiddle.net/MfS3J/15/ ,you asked so many questions.
you can use

```
<a href="#jump_1">header 1</a>
```

to jump

```
<a name="jump_1"></a>
```

instead of js function